# Max from each group LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have tried every possible way and looked up everywhere. I am in frustration because this is really silly.  I want max from each group. I have below records.

```
ID  Custno  paydt                    rcvDt                  Mon    Tue
17  106505  2009-12-31 00:00:00.000 2012-07-11 07:15:04.523 100     3
18  106505  2009-12-31 00:00:00.000 2012-07-11 07:15:04.543 NULL    NULL
19  106505  2010-12-31 00:00:00.000 2012-07-11 07:15:04.747 3       3
20  106505  2011-12-31 00:00:00.000 2012-07-11 07:15:04.827 3       3
```

result should be group by Custno and paydt and return with max id

```
ID  Custno  paydt                    rcvDt                  Mon    Tue
18  106505  2009-12-31 00:00:00.000 2012-07-11 07:15:04.543 NULL    NULL
19  106505  2010-12-31 00:00:00.000 2012-07-11 07:15:04.747 3   3
20  106505  2011-12-31 00:00:00.000 2012-07-11 07:15:04.827 3   3
```

Tried different way and one of them is below

```
var q = from x in MyTable.ToList()
                        group x by new { x.custno, x.paydt } into g
                        select new MyTable
                        {
                            custno= g.Key.custno,
                            paydt= g.Key.paydt,
                            ID = g.Max(b => b.ID),
                            rcvDt = g.OrderByDescending(a => a.ID).First().rcvDt ,
                            mon = g.OrderByDescending(a => a.ID).First().mon,
                            tue = g.OrderByDescending(a => a.ID).First().tue
                        };
```

will appreciate help!

Comment: Your query does not look wrong. What does it return?

Comment: It return max from each Column :(

Comment: Mon and tue are returning 100 and 3 instead of null null

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
var q = MyTable.GroupBy(x => new {x.custno, x.paydt})
               .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(i => i.ID).First());
```

This groups using your same logic.  It performs the same grouping you were using, but then selects, from within each group, the first record after sorting the group by ID descending.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var q = MyTable.GroupBy(x => new { x.custno, x.paydt }).Max(y=> y.Max(z => z.ID));
```

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its possible to do in a single query, but you always can do it in two steps:

```
    var maxIds = MyTable.GroupBy(x => new {x.custno, x.paydt}).Select(g => g.Max(i => i.ID));
    var result = MyTable.Where(x => maxIds.Contains(x.ID));
```